# Node + express - Can´t find my javascript files in apparently correct path

Tags: node.js, express, path

I am using express.static to define the 'root' of my files, but it seems to have no effect. The server script is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
server = require('http').createServer(app);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'js/View'));
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/js/View/output.html');
});
```

In the browser, the output.html is rendering as expected but static files like this script fail to load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wsBodyFrames.js"></script>
```

But the server answer with a 404 error. Why is the path invalid?

Answer (score 1):

`__dirname` doesn’t end with a slash; join it with `path.join` instead.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'js/View')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'js/View/output.html'));
});

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry for the bad grammar!